# element.is() equivalent in Angular jqLite

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Is there a way to find out the type of an element in Angular/jqLite (in this example if it's an input or text field), or do I need jQuery to do this?

The code is:

```
.directive('localize', ['localize', function(localize) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$on('languageChange', function() {
                var localizedText = localize.localizeText(scope.sourceText);
                if (element.is('input, textarea')) { //<--- this right here
                    element.attr('placeholder', localizedText);
                } else {
                    element.text(localizedText);
                }
            });
        }
    };
}])
```

Comment: if({input:1, textarea:1}[element[0].tagName.toLowerCase()]){ ... }

Comment: @davdavis Thank you very much, this is the right answer. Please post your solution as an answer, so I can accept it!

Comment: @dandavis also could you please tell me what sytnax you used? It works, but I've never seen it before..

Comment: it's called a look-up-table, and it can replace a switch when you need to compare one value to one-of-the-above values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use .tagName please see here http://jsbin.com/kejeco/1/edit?html,js,console,output

```
.directive('localize', ['localize', function(localize) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$on('languageChange', function() {
                var localizedText = localize.localizeText(scope.sourceText);
                if (element[0].tagName  ==="INPUT" || element[0].tagName  ==="TEXTAREA") {

                    element.attr('placeholder', localizedText);
                } else {
                    element.text(localizedText);
                }
            });
        }
    };
}])
```

Comment: Strangely this also gives me undefined, however getting the base element of the jqLite object with `element[0].tagName` as suggested by [dandavis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25712832/element-is-equivalent-in-angular-jqlite#comment40194358_25712832) works nicely.

Comment: @TheRebel, that's right I've made the typo error, element return array of object so you have to check fist object in your case.

Comment: @ sss, thanks for correcting this, if dandavis is not posting his solution as a proper answer, I'll set yours as accepted

Comment: Perfect for this use case, but does nto seem to be exact alternative for all use cases of .is of JQuery

Answer (score 1):

While this doesn't solve ALL `is()` equivalents, it does provide a simple way to determine the element type within a directive link:

The `attrs` also contains a property named `type`, which will contain the element type:

```
.directive('localize', ['localize', function(localize) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$on('languageChange', function() {
                var localizedText = localize.localizeText(scope.sourceText);
                if ( 'input' == attrs.type || 'textarea' == attrs.type ) {
                    element.attr('placeholder', localizedText);
                } else {
                    element.text(localizedText);
                }
            });
        }
    };
}])
```